# Getting values from undefined indexes in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I get an array from a request:

```
 $years['id'] = $request->get('years');
```

which if I do dd looks like this:

```
 array:3 [
  0 => "5"
  1 => "6"
  2 => "7"
  ]
```

In my query I would like to get records based on the values from that array, like this:

```
qy.years_id whereIN ({$years['id']})
```

but I get an error

```
Array to string conversion
```

I have edited to whole thing and this is how the query looks now:

```
$years = $request->get('years');
$subjects = $request->get('subjects');
$topics = $request->get('topics');
//get all the questions by given parameters
$qr =<<<SQL
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT q.id) AS questions_count
FROM
  questions q
LEFT JOIN
  question_year qy
ON
  q.id = qy.question_id
LEFT JOIN
  question_subject qs
ON
  q.id = qs.question_id
LEFT JOIN
  question_topic qt
ON
  q.id = qt.question_id
WHERE
  qy.year_id IN ({$years})
  SQL;
if ($subjects <> 0) {
    $qr .= <<<SQL
    AND
      qs.subject_id IN ({$subjects})
SQL;
}
if ($topics <> 0) {
    $qr .=<<<SQL
    AND
      qt.topic_id IN ({$topics})
SQL;
}
$result = $this->getReadConnection()->query($qr);
$result->setFetchMode(Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dboutput = array();

foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
    $dboutput['count'] = $value['questions_count'];
}
return $dboutput;
```

But even here I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),    expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Comment: Show us the code that is throwing errors, as far as I can see it's a very simple array and shouldn't require any nifty methods to show the data.

Comment: what I need is to make this indexes named as id, so that I am able to get those values like this $myarr['id'], because I would like to use the array of ids in a database query, and get only records that have a matching id with an id from the array

Comment: ... What? Array keys are **unique** which means that you cannot use the same array key multiple times at the same array level, could you edit your question with the code you are having issues with and how you'd like your array to look?

Comment: Still no idea what you're asking. To access the values you do `$arr[0]` to get `"5"`. No more, no less. What else do you need?

Comment: check out:   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: Oh hey, *finally* an actual concrete question.

Comment: And there are a metric ton of duplicates for it! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=where+in+array+mysql

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it like this:

```
"qy.years_id IN (" . implode(', ', $years['id']) . ")"
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: While you're at it... SQL doesn't have the keyword "wherein", although it arguably *should*. :)

Comment: True, but I'm not sure if he's using something to translate that query language to SQL. Assumed it would be some doctrine stuff in there, and since I've never used doctrine I wouldn't know. ^^

Comment: Quite honestly, I doubt that. ;)

Comment: when I use that, I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: This kind of code wouldn't cause that... Maybe you could post your actual fragment of code so we can see what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marco You should use $years = implode (', ', $request->get('years')); That should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you or show us some code with the error.

```
$array = [5, 6, 7];

//  Method1:
echo $array[0]; // Returns 5

// Method3:
$buff = "";

// Method2:
foreach($array as $value){
    $buff .= $value; // For Method3
    echo $value; // Returns 567
}

echo $buff; // Returns 567
```

Comment: This is a very cumbersome way to make a print_r() or var_dump() alternative though.

Comment: Or a simple `echo implode(' ',$array);`

Comment: @César : I know, but Marco wants to 'extract somehow these values', how can you get the value and use them when you var_dump() the array? Right, not at all.